# How to find an unknown parallel side of a trapezium?

Tags: geometry

This question was asked in Nov 2015 CIE IGCSE maths exam.

[image]

In part b)i, in order to find the volume, you have to find the width of surface of the water. Now I did find the unknown width using similar triangles and got the correct volume.

However in the Examiner Report it was mentioned that the best method was to find the average of 35 and 25 and use it as the width of the surface of water. Here is the excerpt from the examiner report.

[image]

My question is what is the mathematical basis for finding an unknown side as mentioned in the examiner report?

**Note for anyone wondering about the examiner comment**:  The examiners are talking about the median of the trapezoid, which is a line halfway between two bases. The median is always average of two bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average of the two bases of that trapezoid is equal to the length of the water level.
[image]

Comment: Say the height of the water was 8cm, then how do you find the width of the water surface?

Comment: @DeltaCharlie, in any triangle if you draw a line parallel to a side, that line will divide the other two sides proportionally. It means that in the picture that I sent we have: $\frac{AM}{MN}=\frac{AB}{BC}$ which is $\frac{6}{MN}=\frac{12}{5}$ therefore $MN=2.5$. And now if the water level is $8$, we can write the same again: $\frac{AM}{MN}=\frac{AB}{BC}$ and we put $8$ for $AM$ and we get: $\frac{8}{MN}=\frac{12}{5}$ which $MN=\frac{40}{12}=\frac{10}{3}$

Comment: I understand your method very clearly. But in the examiner report it is mentioned that "many students recognized that the water width is the average of 25 and 35". My question is how do you recognize at the outset, that the width will be average of 25 & 35  without using any similar triangles?

Comment: @DeltaCharlie, As i mentioned above, "in any triangle if you draw a line parallel to a side, that line will divide the other two sides proportionally." This is something that you should know in geometry.

Comment: So your statement essentially means that triangle AMN is similar to triangle ABC, right?

Comment: @DeltaCharlie, yes those two triangles are always similar, their corresponding angles are equal.

Comment: Is there any other method for finding the water width without using the similar triangles aspect?

Comment: I just found what the Examiners meant when they said the width of the water can be found out by the average of 25 and 35. They are talking about the median of the trapezoid, which is a line halfway between two bases. The median is always average of two bases. Anyway I really appreciate your answers and the time you took to help me. Thank you.

Comment: Were you talking about the median when you said "The average of the two bases of that trapezoid is equal to the length of the water level.". I am sorry I didnt catch it back then.

Comment: @DeltaCharlie, yes that is exactly what I meant.